# Adding border on hover causes flickering

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK, so I'm trying to create a test "grid", built on top of BootStrap rows.

Whenever the user hovers over an item, a border is added.

However, this causes the grid to "move" weirdly. Is it because of the paddings? What should I do in order to fix that?

Here's the demo: `http://83.212.101.132/angjs/ang2.html`

Comment: Adding some actual code is a usual requirement for this type of question (usually in a demo from JSfiddle.net).

Comment: It will be better for future reference(helpful for others having same problem)  if you move that demo to jsfiddle and add your code here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its because the box-model, you can try with `box-sizing: border-box;` but it will not help I guess. I suggest you to use a transparent border on it.

```
#components .wrp {
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid transparent;
border-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding :

```
#components .wrp {
padding: 10px;
border: 2px solid transparent;/* this will fixe it!*/
}
```

wil fixe it!

or if you want to use `box-shadow`

```
#components .wrp {
padding: 10px;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px transparent;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

hovering

```
#components .wrp:hover {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #333;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it was because of padding.

Your border width is 2px, if you reduce your padding on hover by 2px, the flickering is removed..

```
#components .wrp:hover {
    border: 2px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When hovering, the CSS is adding a 2px border - this means it is having to find space for 4px total (top to bottom) and another 4px (left and right). The flickering is caused by your elements being shifted slightly to accommodate the extra pixel space required.

There are two alternative ways to fix this:

1) Use 'outline' instead of 'border'

2) Set an identical but transparent border on your elements so that when you hover, only the colour of the border is changing

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would normally add a transparent border on non-hovered elements. This means that the elements are not increasing in size when hovered because they already have a border.

```
#components .wrp {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
}
```